# Closed form of multiple roots for zero-discriminant cubic

Tags: cubics

When a cubic equation has a zero discriminant, and thus has real roots with multiplicity, is there any closed-form solution available for such roots? All sources I found just mention either the Cardano-method roots (which involve complex numbers even if the result is real), or the Viète/Descartes trigonometric form for the real roots, but they require a negative non-zero discriminant (if the discriminant is zero, you get an indetermination at the arccos of infinity).

Is there any closed-form (without complex numbers) for the roots when the discriminant is zero?

Comment: Any double root of $P(x)$ will be a root of the derivative $P'(x)$ as well, which is a quadratic and can be solved directly, or find $\gcd(P,P')$ by long  division.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this, but the derivative roots are different to the double root that you can see in Claude's answer. The simple root is different too,

Comment: The expression posted by Claude may *look* different, but gives in fact the same double root. Note that the expression is *only* valid if $\Delta = 0$ so at that point there is an additional known relationship between $a,b,c,d$. Because of that, such expressions don't necessarily have a *unique* representation in terms of the coefficients. For an unrelated trivial example, if you have two variables $u,v$ and you know that $u+v=1$ then the expressions $u-v$ and $u^2 - v^2$ are equivalent.

Comment: For a concrete example, say $P(x)=(x-1)^2(x+2)= x^3+x^2-5 x+3$. Then $P'(x)=3 x^2+2 x-5$ and calculating the $\gcd$ using the Euclidian algorithm gives in the end $\gcd(P(x),P'(x))=x-1$. Therefore $x=1$ is a root of $P'(x)$ and a double root of $P(x)$. Alternatively, if you first verify that the discriminant $\Delta=0$ then the same $x=1$ is given by Claude's formula $\big(9 \cdot 1 \cdot 3 - 1 \cdot (-5)\big) / \big(2 \cdot (1 \cdot 1 - 3 \cdot 1 \cdot (-5))\big) = 32 / (2 \cdot 16) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the cubic equation $$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$$ if $\Delta=0$  and $\Delta_0=b^2-3ac=0$ are equal to $0$,  the equation has a triple root 
$$x=-\frac{b}{3a}$$
If $\Delta=0$  and $\Delta_0\neq 0$ ,  there are a double root
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{9ad-bc}{2(b^2-3ac)}$$
and a simple root,
$$x_3=\frac{4abc-9a^2d-b^3}{a(b^2-3ac)}$$

Have look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't dig in that page enough, but it was definitely there!